# Use PHP to check if website has product in stock

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I'm looking to recreate something like this: https://gist.github.com/cogwirrel/8286566 in PHP.

Essentially, I buy and resell many products, and would like to have a script that I could run every morning to ensure all the products I am selling are in stock from my supplier. In my head it seems a simple "if x product web page shows string "Out of Stock" then alert, x product is out of stock" and my basic knowledge of PHP tells me I could do it but I'm just not sure how to search a specific web page for a string using PHP

How hard would this be to achieve? If anyone could point me to any material to do so I would appreciate it. The above link is exactly what I'm after but I have no knowledge in Ruby on Rails at all and wouldn't know where to begin!

Thanks so much and if I need to narrow this any further please let me know

Comment: Haven't tried it but http://webscraper.io/ might be of use to you. Otherwise, if you want to write your own script you can use `file_get_contents()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with PHP if that is what you're familiar with. You could do the following:

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents("http://supplierwebsite.com");
if (strstr($contents, "Not in stock")) {
   // it's not in stock
}
?>
```